# Compatibilidad de Netbeans 8.2 con TomCat

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

Necesito realizar un sistema en Jsp, servlets con java 7 que estará muy ligado a procedimientos a MySql. Tengo entendido que TomCat 7 trabaja con Java 6 y Tomcat 8 con Java 7. Mi problema es el siguiente. Negreaba 8.2 solo me soporta tomcat 8.0.27 y en la página de tomcat esta es 8.5 y no encuentro la 8.0.27. Antes trabajé con Glass Fish pero me recomiendan mejor Tomcat ya que usare servlets. Qué solución puedo obtener para trabajar con Java 7 o Java 8 usando Tomcat ya que usare SERVLETS. Gracias quien me puedo ayudar la verdad estoy un poco confundida y nose que hacer

Comment: Hola @Angelita El sitio ideal para ese tipo de preguntas es [Software Recomendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) aquí probablemente la cierren porque *pedir recomendaciones* se parece mucho a pedir opiniones.

Comment: Hola, qué pena no sabía gracias por tu comentario.

Comment: ¿ Ya revisaste NetBeans 11.2 ? Quizás resuelva tu problema.

Comment: Si ya probé apache 11.2 pero muchos proyectos que tenía no me funcionan pero en netbeans 8.2 si me funcionan la verdad nose porque

Comment: trabajo con netBeans 8.2 y TomCat 9 funciona perfecto, adelante.

Answer (score 0):

Estoy bajando la version de tomcat que necesitas.
Fijate si es la de este link que te paso:

https://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.0.27/bin/

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/399473)